# Closed form solution for quadratic optimization

Tags: linear-algebra, optimization, convex-optimization, nonlinear-optimization

Is there any closed form solution for the following optimization problem:
\begin{align}
&\min_{\mathbf{X},\alpha} \mathrm{Tr}[(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{X})^{\mathrm{H}}] + \alpha\\
&\mathrm{s.t.}\qquad  [\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{H}}]_{i,i}\leq \alpha, \qquad\forall i, 
\end{align}
where $\mathbf{X}_{n\times m}$, $\mathbf{B}_{m\times n}$, $\mathbf{A}_{m\times m}$ are complex matrices with $m\leq n$, $[.]_{i,i}$ denotes the $i$th diagonal entries of matrix. This problem could be considered as the following unconstrained optimization problem
\begin{align}
\min_{\mathbf{X}} \mathrm{Tr}[(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{X})(\mathbf{A}-\mathbf{B}\mathbf{X})^{\mathrm{H}}] + \max_{i} [\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{H}}]_{i,i}, 
\end{align}
and $\alpha = \max_{i} [\mathbf{X}\mathbf{X}^{\mathrm{H}}]_{i,i}$.

Comment: Please do not use "$n$" to mean two different things in the same context.

Comment: I dont understand your comment.

Comment: You are using $n$ initially as an index, but then later you use to represent a dimension.

Comment: Sorry, I correct it.

Comment: You can decouple $\mathbf X$ and $\alpha$: $$\begin{align}
&\min_{\mathbf{X},\alpha} \mathrm{Tr}[(\mathbf{A}-\alpha\mathbf{BX})(\mathbf{A}-\alpha\mathbf{BX})^{\mathrm{H}}] + \alpha\\
&\mathrm{s.t.}\qquad  [\mathbf{XX}^{\mathrm{H}}]_{i,i}\leq 1, \qquad\forall i, 
\end{align}$$
which then reduces to $$\min\big(\mathrm{Tr}[\mathbf{AA}^H] + \alpha(1-\mathrm{Tr}[\mathbf{A}^H\mathbf{BX} + \mathbf{A}\mathbf{B}^H\mathbf{X}^H]) + \alpha^2\mathrm{Tr}[\mathbf{BX}\mathbf{B}^H\mathbf{X}^H]\big)$$ which allows you to easily find the minimal $\alpha$.

Comment: Then, $\alpha$ is based on $\mathbf{X}$? I cannot understand how will be the answer then.